Sending at commands to sim7600 and not receiving a response on Raspberry Pi Zero
I have been searching for a few days but I have not found any results. I have a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W and a sim7600 hat and I want to send at commands to it using a program I wrote. When I use minicom as sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB2, the at command response is sent from sim7600 to Raspberry Pi just fine. But when I run my program, I do not receive any response from sim7600 when sending at commands. I know that the at commands are working properly in my program because if I enter the AT+CRESET command in my program, the module is reset and then if I close my program and immediately run the program again, I can see the response to the at commands I send but again after a few seconds there is no response.
this is my c# code:
class Program

{
static SerialPort portUSB;
static void Main()
{
    
    Console.Write("select Port:");
    string port = Console.ReadLine();
    portUSB = new SerialPort(port, 115200);
    

        Console.WriteLine("connecting to ttyUSB2 ...");
        portUSB.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        portUSB.DtrEnable = true;
        portUSB.RtsEnable = true;
        portUSB.ReadTimeout = 2000;
        portUSB.WriteTimeout = 2000;
        
        portUSB.DataReceived += PortUSB_DataReceived;
        portUSB.Open();


    Console.WriteLine("Write and Enter to send Message and press ctrl+c to exit");


    while (true)
    {

        if (Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            string message = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                SendMessage(message);
            }
        }

        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}

private static void PortUSB_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

    Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
    sp.DiscardInBuffer();
    sp.DiscardOutBuffer();
    Console.Write(indata);
}

static void SendMessage(string message)
{
    try
    {
        if (portUSB.IsOpen)
        {
            portUSB.Write(message + "\r\n");

            Console.WriteLine("Command Sent " + message);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ttyUSB2 Not open!");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

}

}
